# How to format following date time value as it is in the database?

Tags: java, date, date-formatting, localdate

I'm using Java 8 `LocalDateTime` and convert it into a `Timestamp` format. output of the `timeStampOfTodayMidNight` is = `2019-07-03 00:00:00.0` . But I want in this format = `03-JUL-19 15:05:31`. I tried lot to format this but could not. can anyone help me here?
Thanks.

```
LocalTime midnight = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of(environment.getProperty("axipay.time.zone")));
LocalDateTime todayMidnight = LocalDateTime.of(today, midnight);
LocalDateTime tomorrowMidnight = todayMidnight.plusDays(1);
Date timeStampOfTodayMidNight = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(todayMidnight);
```

Comment: You absolutely should _not_ be storing your timestamps as text in your database, and you should not have the need to convert your dates into the format `03-JUL-19 15:05:31`.  Instead, let JDBC or your ORM layer (e.g. Hibernate) handle storing `LocalTime` automatically.

Comment: SIr,
Im working on existing project. So i cant change the values and the formats here has.

Comment: what have you tried? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: What's the data type of your database column?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Its DATE

Comment: Then you don't need to convert it into a specific format, use standard java types as mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: Provided that you are using JDBC 4.2 or a modern JPA implementation, you have nothing to use the poorly deigned and outdated `Date` and `Timestamp` for.

Comment: Im working on a project which has been developing since 2015. No JPA here. So i cant help to change that existing methods.

Comment: If already using JDBC 4.2, my comment is still valid. If not, consider upgrading, it requires no changes to your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat`.

Try this :

```
LocalTime midnight = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
LocalDateTime todayMidnight = LocalDateTime.of(today, midnight);
LocalDateTime tomorrowMidnight = todayMidnight.plusDays(1);
Date timeStampOfTodayMidNight = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(todayMidnight);
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss", Locale.US);
String formatDate = format.format(timeStampOfTodayMidNight); 
System.out.println(formatDate.toUpperCase());
```

Output :

```
03-JUL-19 12:00:00
```

Comment: No, do not use SimpleDateFormat. Instead use DateTimeFormatter

Comment: Don't format into a string. Just save the `LocalDate`. And even if you had needed to format into a string, you still shouldn't have used `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the fact i realize is, if your database column in timestamp format and POJO class relevant fields surrounded with DATE data type, you actually dont want to pass formatted date. just pass DATE type.